# Is it possible to prerender Angular Universal and host on Firebase Hosting and Function?

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-universal

I'd like to host my Angular 11 PWA (Universal) on Firebase but want to prerender the pages to improve page loading speeds. Is this possible?
I know that Angular Universal with server-side rendering is possible to host on Firebase Hosting and Functions. If not, I'd stick with App Engine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, you can tell Angular which pages you want to pre-render using the "prerender" definition in angular.json. More info: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-universal/

Answer (score 0):

You can, I personally have my blog setup on Firebase with prerendering. But I don't run the usual prerender, what I do is run a local express to generate the static files before I deploy. But you can use the normal prerendering feature of Angular.
I even blogged about https://garage.sekrab.com/posts/prerendering-in-angular-part-ii

Update, firebase now documents Angular hosting as beta:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/angular